# hide a div in react when there is no anchor tag in it

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have a `react code` `(just a snippet, its not a complete  code)` as shown below which shows the list of programs on the webpage. `Line A` in the react code below renders all list of program on the webpage.

**react code**:

```
const renderPrograms = () => {
    return programs.map((program, index)=>{
        return (
            <a href={program.url} key={index}>
                <div className="program" >
                    <div class="hello-world">{program.name}</div>
                </div >
            </a>
        )
    })
}


return(
<div class="parent-div">
    <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
        <h5>Hello World</h5>            
    </div>
    <div className ="abc-def">  
        <h5>Programs</h5>
        {programs && renderPrograms()}   {/*Line A*/}
    </div>
</div> 
)
```

The above `react` code renders the following **html code** at runtime:

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
        <h5>Hello World</h5>            
    </div>
    <div class="abc-def">
       <h5>Programs</h5>
       <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <div class="program">  
              <div class="hello-world">TYUV</div>
            </div>
       </a>
       <a href="https://www.twitter.com/">
            <div class="program"> 
              <div class="hello-world">SGHS</div>
            </div>  
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

When `Line A` does not render anything, my div (`<div className ="abc-def">`) will look like this at run time:

```
<div class="abc-def">   
  <h5>Programs</h5>
</div>
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in my react code above so that when Line A doesn't render anything then `<div class="abc-def"><h5>Programs</h5></div>` should not display on the webpage.

Comment: So the way there would be an `a` element is if you have programs. Why don't you add a class 'hide' ( this is an option ) if there are no programs : `programs.length === 0` and use css `hide { display: none } `

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks for the comment. I am wondering if you can explain me in an example. I  thought this can be done with css only but `<h5>Programs</h5>` tag will be present in all cases so its impossible to do with css.

Comment: @MihaiT I found a solution on their official website https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html Can I use that to add a class ?

Comment: search how to add a className conditionally in react . The answers and my comment should be more than enough for you to solve this very easy issue. You could also not render the div alltogheter if you don't have programs. { programs && ( <div .... ) }

Comment: Something like this `{ programs && 
 (<div className ="abc-def"> <h5>Programs</h5> {programs && renderPrograms()} {/*Line A*/} </div>)}` ?

Answer (score 1):

They should be part of the condition:

```
return(
    programs.length > 0 && <div className ="abc-def">  
        <h5>Programs</h5>
        {renderPrograms()} 
    </div>
)
```

I changed the condition to check for length, otherwise you'll get a `0` instead of nothing, when empty

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. I've edited my question a bit. There is one parent div on the div which I want to hide. I am wondering how the code will work then

Comment: Just move the condition up a level

Answer (score 1):

Try change this lines:

```
    <div className ="abc-def">  
        <h5>Programs</h5>
        {programs && renderPrograms()}   {/*Line A*/}
    </div>
```

into this:

```
    { programs && ( 
        <div className ="abc-def">  
            <h5>Programs</h5>
            {renderPrograms()}   {/*Line A*/}
        </div>
    ) }
```

Now without programs nothing is displayed.

Comment: After few minor changes, it worked for me. 
    `{ programs.length>0 && ( 
        <div className ="abc-def">  
            <h5>Programs</h5>
            {renderPrograms()}   {/*Line A*/}
        </div>
    ) }`

Comment: In case if `length<0`, I am wondering what changes I need to do display this `<h2>Hello World</h2>` on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a className like this:

```
<div className={`abc-def ${programs.length ? "hidden" : ""}`}
```

Or from the parent componet,  you can choose to not render this component with `<div>`

Comment: something like this ? `<div className={`abc-def ${programs.length ? "hidden" : ""}`}
    <h5>Programs</h5>
    {programs && renderPrograms()}
</div>`

Comment: I'll try making an real example

Comment: @flash https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-oskar-wyws5?file=/src/App.js  here's a version where `<Programs>` return nothing if `programs` list is empty

Comment: It returns a fragment (`<></>`), returning an empty string has similar effect (nothing rendered in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to hide it using CSS, you also can choose to not render it at all by returning nothing from your function

```js
const RenderPrograms = ({ programs = [] }) => {

  if (!programs.length) {
    return []
  }

  return (
    <div className="abc-def">
      <h5>Programs</h5>
      {programs.map((program, index) =>
        <a href={program.url} key={index}>
          <div className="program">
            <div>{program.name}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <RenderPrograms />,
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I saw your code but I am bit confused how I can integrate it as I am not a very strong react developer. In the question above if this line `{programs && renderPrograms()}` doesn't render nothing then this class `<div className ="abc-def"> ` should not be displayed on the webpage or `display:none` css is applied. 

I am wondering if you can give me pointers how I can integrate your code with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your class in a template string and using a ternary operator to display a certain class when some state value is true.

```
          <div className={`${stateValue ? "name-of-class-with-hide" : "abc-def"}`}>
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can let me know how to integrated this code my current code above.  In the question above if this line `{programs && renderPrograms()}` doesn't render nothing then this class `<div className ="abc-def">`  should not be displayed on the webpage or `display:none` css is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution. All you need to do is move the `<h5>Programs</h5>` inside the condition and modify the condition slightly as shown in following snippet.

```
    <div className ="abc-def">  
        {
            programs.length > 0 && (
               <div>
                 <h5>Programs</h5>
                 <RenderPrograms programs = {programs}/>
               </div>
            )
        }
    </div>
```

Note that I have modified the `RenderPrograms` function as well to accept arguments.

Following is a full snippet.

```js
function RenderPrograms(props) {
    return props.programs.map((program, index)=>{
        return (
            <a href={program.url} key={index}>
                <div className="program" >
                    <div className="hello-world">{program.name}</div>
                </div >
            </a>
        )
    });
}

function MyApp() {
  const programs=[
                      {name:'program 1', url: 'https://url1.com'},
                      {name:'program 2', url: 'url2'},
                      {name:'program 3', url: 'url3'},
                    ];
  const programs1 = []; // empty program list
  return(
    <div class="parent-div">
        
        <h1>When programs list is not empty</h1>
        {/*Above line is just for explanation -- you may remove it*/}
        <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
            <h5>Hello World</h5>            
        </div>
        <div className ="abc-def">  
            {
                programs.length > 0 && (
                   <div>
                     <h5>Programs</h5>
                     <RenderPrograms programs = {programs}/>
                   </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
        
        {/*Below code is just for explanation -- you may remove it*/}
        <hr />
        <h1>When programs list is empty</h1>
        
        <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
            <h5>Hello World</h5>            
        </div>
        <div className ="abc-def">  
            {
                programs1.length > 0 && (
                   <div>
                     <h5>Programs</h5>
                     <RenderPrograms programs = {programs1}/>
                   </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
        
    </div> 
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move rendering of programs into RenderPrograms component. Make RenderPrograms component purelu functional and pass data to it via props (Instead of using function).

```
 const RenderPrograms = ({ programs }) => {
  let disp = programs.map((program, index) => {
    return (
      <a href={program.url} key={index}>
        <div className="program">
          <div class="hello-world">{program.name}</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    );
  });

  return disp || <span />;
};
```

then use `RenderPrograms` to render programs in main component (One with logis for loading programs).

```
     // let programs = [
  //   {
  //     url: "test1.com",
  //     name: "test1"
  //   },
  //   {
  //     url: "test2.com",
  //     name: "test2"
  //   }
  // ];

  let programs = [];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="parent-div">
        <div className="pqr-xyz">
          <h5>Hello World</h5>
        </div>
        <div className="abc-def">
          <h5>Programs</h5>

          <RenderPrograms programs={programs} />
          {/* {programs && renderPrograms()} Line A */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You can play around with this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-monad-kzi7i?file=/src/App.js)